# jsf h:inputText component appear based on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf, components

I need to have a jsf h:inputText component appear on a web page based on whether a javascript test condition is true or not.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let JSF render it with CSS `display` property initially set to `none` and have JavaScript to toggle this to `block`.

E.g.

```html
<h:inputText id="inputId" styleClass="hide" />
```

with this CSS

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

and this JS

```js
if (someCondition) {
    document.getElementById("formId:inputId").style.display = "block";
}
```

You'll only possibly run into problems with regard to input processing and conversion/validation. This input field is **always** submitted to the server, even when still hidden by CSS. Much better would be to evaluate that condition in JSF instead so that you can use the JSF component's `rendered` attribute.

Comment: once the component is visible, how do I hid it again? .style = "hide"

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it on page depending on your javascript condition. Something like `$('.class-of-input').hide();`